# Hibernate - proper one-to-one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

How should I map one-to-one association between A and B classes in case A.id != B.id (as hibernate offers for one-to-one association) and I want to have an association like A.b_id = B.id instead? Should it be mapped as many-to-one (for A) association? Bidirectionality is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the name of the join column in addition to the OneToOne, and hibernate will join on anything you want.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
private B b;
```

The conventional way to map it in XML is as a unique many-to-one.

```
<many-to-one name="b" 
    column="b_id" 
    unique="true"/>
```

Comment: hmmmm. how do it look like in hbm.xml?

Comment: afaik there's a column="b_id" attribute you can add to the one-to-one, but I am not well versed in xml based hibernate.

Comment: @Andrey : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-121 The hibernate reference manual is the best place to look for reference information about Hibernate.